# Django - get original object values in form_valid for UpdateView?

Tags: django, django-forms

Using Django's `UpdateView`, I'm looking to update a version number if certain fields in the `form.instance` are actually updated.  This requires comparing the values of these fields to the original value before the user set the updated value.  In `form_valid`, is it possible to access the original object's values before the updating occurred?

For example:

```py
class PostUpdateView(UpdateView):
   model = Post
   fields = ['title', 'body']

   def form_valid(self, form):
      new_body = form.instance.body
      original_body = 'how do we get this?'
      if new_body != original_body:
         version = form.instance.body_version
         form.instance.body_version = version + 1
         form.save()
      return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: The `initial` dict should contain the initial values. To check if the values changed it's easier to do `"field_name" in form.changed_data`.